# Missing required parameter for route in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have a code below which is running in the laravel 5.1 and when I upgraded into 5.2 I got this error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: ] [URI: operations/items/{item_id}/displaybulkunits].

Since I have upgraded to 5.2 I remove `Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider::class` in the config/app.php in the providers  in order to run the upgraded laravel.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off" id="bulkUnit" name="bulkUnit" role="form"  method="POST" action="{{ action('Operations\ItemController@createBulkUOM')}}" >
```

Comment: Did you follow the upgrade guide fully? There are several things required.

Comment: I think it's missing some code to help you better. You may show what you're doing at the end of `createBulkUOM`, or how you defined the route for `createBulkUOM`

Comment: Also, show the route you are trying to request